# Text Field date values are changing date format in Power BI portal

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

All the text fields in power bi desktop dashboard are in the format of dd.mm.yyyy but they are changing back to mm/dd/yyyy format in app.powerbi.com after publishing. Could you please let me know why this is happening with text fields only since date fields are showing in dd.mm.yyyy in power bi portal also.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problems developing reports with date-parameters in PowerBI Report Builder and publishing them to PowerBI Premium.
The problem is the regional settings of the two. My RB (SSRS in a new jacket) is configured in English, with regional EN/US (mm-dd-yyyy) and my PBI-Webportal is configured in Dutch (dd-mm-yyyy).
When you try to use the same input, the workaround is to set the date-parameter to text (for example 01-10-2021), and convert it in your query back to a date, using for example:

```
SQL
parameter: @date DATE
DECLARE @this_date NVARCHAR(10)
SET @this_date = CONVERT(nvarchar, @date, 105)

ORACLE
TO_DATE(@this_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```